# Delegate not triggering function in another class after broadcasting

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I'm working with Unreal Engine 5.1.1 and have run into an issue with delegates. Specifically, the `OnMessageReceived` delegate in my `UWebSocketHandler` class doesn't seem to trigger the `HandleMessageReceived` function in my `UCustomGameInstanceBase class, even though I believe I have set up the binding correctly.

Here's the relevant code:

**UCustomGameInstanceBase.h**

```
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam(FOnMessageReceivedBP, const FString&, Message);

UCLASS()
class SomeProjectName_API UCustomGameInstanceBase : public UGameInstance
{
    ...
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintAssignable, Category = "WebSocket")
    FOnMessageReceivedBP OnMessageReceivedBP;
    ...
    void HandleMessageReceived(const FString& Message);
};
```

**UCustomGameInstanceBase.cpp**

```
void UCustomGameInstanceBase::ConnectToWebSocket()
{
    if (WebSocketMgr)
    {
        WebSocketMgr->OnMessageReceived.AddDynamic(this, &UCustomGameInstanceBase::HandleMessageReceived);
        WebSocketMgr->ConnectToWebSocket(AccessToken, WSUrl);
    }
}

void UCustomGameInstanceBase::HandleMessageReceived(const FString& Message)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("HandleMessageReceived!!!"));
    OnMessageReceivedBP.Broadcast(Message);
}
```

UWebSocketHandler.h

```
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam(FOnMessageReceivedDelegate, const FString&, Message);
UCLASS(Blueprintable)
class SomeProjectName_API UWebSocketHandler : public UObject
{
    ...
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintAssignable, Category = "WebSocket")
    FOnMessageReceivedDelegate OnMessageReceived;
    ...
};
```

**UWebSocketHandler.cpp**

```
void UWebSocketHandler::HandleWebSocketConnected()
{
    ...
    OnMessageReceived.Broadcast(messageString);
}
```

When the `HandleWebSocketConnected` function is called in the `UWebSocketHandler` class, it broadcasts the `OnMessageReceived` delegate. I expected the `HandleMessageReceived` function in the `UCustomGameInstanceBase` class to be called, but it wasn't.

I've confirmed that the `HandleWebSocketConnected` method does run and `broadcast` the message and that the `ConnectToWebSocket` in `UCustomGameInstanceBase` is called and does bind the delegate.

What might be causing the delegate not to trigger the function in another class?

Answer (score 0):

Since `FOnMessageReceivedDelegate UWebSocketHandler::OnMessageReceived` is a dynamic multicast delegate, it needs to bind to a `UFUNCTION`. In your current example, `UCustomGameInstanceBase::HandleMessageReceived` does not seem to be marked as `UFUNCTION`.

If you don't need your `UWebSocketHandler::OnMessageReceived` to be exposed to Blueprint, you can use a (faster) non-dynamic multicast delegate and bind it to a lambda. Otherwise just mark it with the macro.